# Using selenium to select an SVG element, but cannot find it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, svg

Been looking at some of the previous stackoverflow responses on using Selenium to select an SVG element, in my situation it would be a gym spot (sample URL included): https://www.barrys.com/schedule/castro/?_mt=%2Fschedule%2Fdaily%2F9627%3FactiveDate%3D2023-02-27

My code includes switching to the iframe, and then selecting the svg circle (in this case, it's spot F-2):

```
    iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[1]')
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[name() = "svg"][@tabindex="39"]'))).click()
```

I was able to double check the XPATH because I could find it in Chrome Developer, but I'm getting the following error:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

If I didn't include the Wait command, I would get the NoSuchElement Exception. Any idea why I can't find the specific svg element and click on it?

*Edit* Trying to click on F-2 for example of this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you post the snapshot of the element for a reference, which one trying to click?

Comment: Just edited main question to include a screenshot of what I'm trying to click on.

Comment: After navigate to the mentioned url I can’t find the page select your spot. How did you reach that page ? What action needs to perform to reach there?

Comment: This is a gym schedule, so courses constantly expire. But an example would be to navigate to: https://www.barrys.com/schedule/castro/ first, Click on "Tues" (or any other day), select a 6:40 PM course in the schedule by clicking the Reserve button, and then selecting the F-2 circle there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not telling Selenium to wait by using sleep() or by using WebDriverWait - then Selenium will not wait even 100 milliseconds and will fail almost immediately.

Your have 2 option here:

Give the WebDriverWait a longer timeout threshold:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[name() = "svg"] 
[@tabindex="39"]'))).click()
```

Or, find the element you need by text:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
'//*[contains(text,"F-2"]'))).click()
```